# Latest article or new development in cross validation?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation

Could anybody provide me a latest material related to Cross validation especially R package?

Answer (score 8):

The following is a recent survey: "A survey of cross-validation procedures for model selection" by Sylvain Arlot and Alain Celisse (Statistics Surveys, Volume 4 (2010), 40-79.)

The full paper can be downloaded by following the PDF link on [this page](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistics-surveys/volume-4/issue-none/A-survey-of-cross-validation-procedures-for-model-selection/10.1214/09-SS054.full).

> **Abstract**
> Used to estimate the risk of an estimator or to perform model selection, cross-validation is a widespread strategy because of its simplicity and its (apparent) universality. Many results exist on model selection performances of cross-validation procedures. This survey intends to relate these results to the most recent advances of model selection theory, with a particular emphasis on distinguishing empirical statements from rigorous theoretical results. As a conclusion, guidelines are provided for choosing the best cross-validation procedure according to the particular features of the problem in hand.

Comment: (+1) A little bit hard to read, though (especially for someone seeking R applications).

Answer (score 7):

Your question is not really precise, but I think the [caret](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/) package and its associated vignettes may be a good start. Quoting the website, it is

> a set of functions that attempt to
>   streamline the process for creating
>   predictive models.

In fact, it depends on a lot of other R packages dedicated to ML (see the list of suggested packages on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html)), but it definitively simplifies the management of cross-validation scheme (k-fold, leave-one-out).

[The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) (Hastie et al.) is available on-line in its second edition, and all illustrations are done in R. Cross-validation is described at length in Chapter 7.